# ASP.NET Core : GraphQl change response content type to application/json

Tags: asp.net-core, graphql, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to change response content type for Graphql endpoints to application/json.

I have tried multiple options, even:

```
// Change the response content type to JSON
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            await next();
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        });
        
// Add GraphQL Server
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapGraphQL("/v1.0/graphql");
        });
        
// Change the response content type to JSON
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            await next();
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        });
```

but it did not help, what do I do?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are trying to do this?

Comment: @DavidG  yes, it is :)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding

```
builder.Services.AddHttpResponseFormatter(new HttpResponseFormatterOptions {
    HttpTransportVersion = HttpTransportVersion.Legacy
});
```